# Tumblr API Avatar

Tags: tumblr

*Complete PHP noob here. I'm trying to write simple php that returns a tumblr avatar. Tumblr has an address you can navigate to, to retreve the blog avatar. For example navigating to:

http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/david.tumblr.com/avatar/512

leads to this:

http://27.media.tumblr.com/avatar_a963092d964b_512.png

I simply want the .png address as a variable. Here's what I got but it just spits out a big page of strange text.

```
<?php
$avatar = file_get_contents("{the link above, I can only have two hyperlinks in a post}");
echo $avatar;
?>
```

I assume the file_get_contents is not what I want to use but I don't know what to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the official [PHP Tumblr Client](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php) and just provide your consumer key.

```
// Authenticate via API Key
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client('yourkeyhere');

// Make the request
$client->getBlogAvatar('yourblog.tumblr.com', 16); //You can choose different size here on the second parameter
```

then this will return the URL of the image.

You can refer to this for more of the Tumblr API Avatar Endpoint and others
https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/blog/avatar

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```php
<?php
$avatar = "http://27.media.tumblr.com/avatar_a963092d964b_512.png";
echo $avatar;
?>
```